# how can i delete all type of file of a name or identity from a folder

Tags: php

what i want to do is upload files with an id and a certain name like (id_name.*) but before upload if there is a file with that name already then delete it.i am trying like this code below ! its in delete function but globe not getting the * sign for type . so, how can i do it ?

```
  public function delete_files($emp_id,$name)
  {     
      $gal = "../public/assets/documents/";
      $File = glob($gal."/".$emp_id."_".$name.".".*);
      unlink($File);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `glob` command is wrong. Try it with:

```
glob($gal . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $emp_id . "_" . $name . ".*");
```